# Get all push notifications received since app was last open

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, cloudkit

I'm creating an iOS 10 app using Xcode 8 and CloudKit. When the app loads, is there any way to read all push notification that have been sent since the last time the app was running?

Answer (score 7):

You can call the following function, `request` contains all notifications delivered

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotificationRequest
 _Nonnull requests) {
           NSLog(@"");
   }];
```

Comment: How about iOS 9?

Comment: The array contains objects of type UNNotification*, not UNNotificationRequest*

Comment: getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler:) returns a list of the app’s notifications that are still displayed in Notification Center. That's not all notifications.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649520-getdeliverednotifications

Answer (score 1):

from ios 10.x we can get pending and delivered notification information using UNUserNotificationCenter

you with a list of the app’s notifications that are still displayed in Notification Center using below function

func getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: @escaping ([UNNotification]) -> Void)

refrer below link [for more details](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter)

Comment: Can we get list of pending notification available in ios 9.x